# How does Spider-Man's spider tracer work?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I had always assumed the spider tracer was a gadget invented by Peter Parker, one that sends a signal to some receiver that Spider-Man carries around when he wants to track a tracer.

However, I recently started reading the 1960s *Amazing Spider-Man* and I have yet to see Spider-Man carrying a receiver. Furthermore, the comics almost seem to imply that these tracers are tied to his spider sense. Hence the question:

**How does Spider-Man's spider tracer work?**

Comment: Do you mean how would it work in *real life*? Because in the comics ...it just *does*...much like everything else. - http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Tracer

Comment: I'm mostly curious if it is purely a Peter Parker invention anyone could use or if it's tied to spider sense.

Comment: That's all answered at the link.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I remember him carrying a receiver in the '60s era cartoon, can't say I recall seeing one in the comics.

Comment: To the close voters: do you have any reason to assume this question is **not** asking for an in-universe explanation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [**Wikia**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Tracer)

[image]

> Spider-Man uses a small electronic receiver to follow the signals of his tracers, ...

[image]

[image]

> but eventually he modifies the tracers to emit a signal he can follow with his spider-sense so that he will be able to know whether or not he is in the proximity of the tracer

Also from the [**Wikia**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Tracer-Tracker)

> A teen Spider-Man invented his first Spider-Tracer to find Doctor Octopus. In those early times he invented a receiver device as well. Spider-Man eventually found out that changing the frequency emitted by the Tracers he could trace them with his Spider-sense.

As for others using the tracers

> Besides Spider-Man, Daredevil can pick up the signal with his Radar Sense from the Spider-Tracers due to his heightened sense of hearing being able to hear the signal. Unlike Spider-Man, it is more difficult for Daredevil to follow the signal, as he must drown out all other sounds around him to maintain focus.

And then:

> Using his resources at Parker Industries, Peter Parker built an improved version of the Spider-Tracer. He made it available for commercial use, having the option of being linked to a webware. The new spider-tracer featured a two-year battery life, was water-proof, and was super durable.

Comment: Do you know the issue # where the receiver is shown? Once I verify that it originally had a receiver then was later modified to work with spider sense, I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: Spider-Man Vol1 Issue 11 - http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spider-Tracer-Tracker/Gallery

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_11

Comment: FWIW, May Parker can't sense the tracers with her spider-sense.

Comment: Parker industries?!

Comment: Yep, Pete's super-rich right now.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if it is an older Spider-Man or newer; from as early as the 1960s cartoon, we have instances of him using a mechanical receiver to track his tracers. By the 1990s, he had found a way to attune the signal to a wavelength which his natural spider sense could resonate with, and thus he could track it within a 5-10 mile radius without any external device.

Give me some time, and I can find both the videos of the 60s cartoon, and a few scans from specific 90s comics where both are used.

I'm guessing after ***Spider-Man: Homecoming***, at least in the MCU, that would be a function picked up by his Stark-built tech suit.

Comment: Have you watched Homecoming at all? He uses the Spider-Tracer in the film and it comes from the suit Tony gives him.