# How does Spider-Man track chemical trails?

Tags: marvel, technology, spider-man

In Spider-Man PS4, Peter Parker has the ability to identify and track certain chemicals he comes across. The identification process is most likely a form of spectroscopy, probably [Raman](https://www.horiba.com/en_en/raman-imaging-and-spectroscopy/). But after identification, he has the ability to "key his lenses" to the "chemical signature". It then shows up on his HUD as a colored path. As far as I know, there are no technologies that can achieve this on such a distance. How does Spider-Man identify the chemical vapors on a distance?

Comment: I think your question will be more suited on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) as its demands details from a game.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you asking what technology would allow/enable this in real life, or if it was ever explained in-universe?  Note: the former is off-topic, and the latter could quite easily be "no."

Comment: When you say "certain chemicals", is there any indication of what he can identify/track and what he can't? Is there a pattern in terms of what all he could identify/track? Also, is it just keying his lenses to lock on to chemical signatures achieved by tech or is the initial identification/tracking done unequivocally using tech too?

Comment: @SatyajitSen I can remember 2 chemicals, one is the fictional devils breath, while the other is a fire supressant. Both are present in gaseous form and left over as trace vapors.

Comment: (1) In the comics, characters such as Reed Richards, Tony Stark etc are routinely able to, with tech of their own design, detect inert stuff at scales and distances that wouldn't be possible in the real world even if the stuff in question wasn't inert and had a strong, distinct signature. No explanation beyond their implicitly being super intelligent is ever extended. It's not like an explanation more reasonable than this can ever be extended given that these are **fictional characters** who are able to detect **fictional stuff** at impossible scales and distances in a **fictional universe**.

Comment: (2) Mostly *fictional stuff* anyway. While Peter wouldn't make the top 10 smartest humans in Marvel, he has been consistently shown to be an immediate peer to them. Moreover, between developing the web fluid, the same web fluid that has been appreciated [by both Reed Richards](https://imgur.com/a/zdO3F) and [by Tony Stark](https://imgur.com/a/XLXPj), at the age of 15 and growing up to do a PhD in biochemistry, it's well known that Peter is written to have a knack for chemistry. It's entirely possible that he accomplished what you talk about solely through tech of his own design.

Comment: (3) Also, Peter has consistently been able to do seemingly impossible stuff via spider-sense, including detecting [radioactivity via "radiation trails"](https://i.imgur.com/HbdATgN_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium) and [radio signals (through long distances)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145738/how-does-spider-mans-spider-tracer-work) that even [Iron Man, due to their low magnitude, hasn't been able to on occasion](https://i.imgur.com/8np92ad.jpg).

Comment: (4) The reason as to why his secondary abilities via spider-sense wax and wane is cause it's derived from the Web of Life and Destiny and for all his secondary abilities via spider-sense to function to their fullest, there needs to be no disturbances in the Web of Life and Destiny, which is almost never. This is why Peter keeps getting tagged by his opponents despite his spider-sense.

Comment: (5) Given that it has never been explicitly stated on panel that there's only a specific type of radioactivity that he can detect, it would not be unreasonable to presume that he can detect all forms which would include gamma radiation as well. Again, if he can detect radio and gamma, which are the least energetic and most energetic forms of electromagnetic radiation respectively, it would not be an unreasonable stretch that he'll be able to detect the types at the mid energy range as well.

Comment: (6) It's known that charged particles give off Lamor radiation, the Lamor radiation of the charged subatomic components of any electrically neutral atom cancel each other due to destructive interference but this doesn't happen perfectly in practice. However, the destructive interference is enough to the extent that the consequent energy signature is highly suppressed, so much so that it's not detectable irl, but that's obviously not a limitation in the comic books.

Comment: (7) If Spider-Man can detect all forms of electromagnetic radiation over large distances, he can justifiably detect and identify any chemical substance based on it's Lamor radiation signature, no matter how miniscule it is, all without any tech. Perhaps his innate sensitivity is further augmented using tech. There was one instance in the comics where he needed a detector for detecting his spider tracers, but even then he could detect it within Manhattan and it was only once the tracer ended up outside Manhattan, that he wasn't able to detect it using his spider sense.

Comment: (8) So his spider sense, at the least, has the range of one NYC borough at it's lowest, but then again, that might not be his usual sensitivity anyway given that his spider sense fluctuates as stated earlier. Even if we presume that he can just strictly detect radio and gamma radiation via his spider-sense and not the mid range, even then it's possible that he uses his tech to generalize his innate sensitivity to the entire spectrum, if not use tech for this operation in its entirety as stated in the beginning.

Comment: (9) I have provided scans in a few instances. However, if you need scans for the other claims, let me know!